# Is there a way to do multiple conditional statements with decision variables in Gurobi / Python Api?

Tags: python, linear-programming, gurobi

Hi Guys I am trying to create a LP model but currently I am stuck with writing one constraint. Logical it should sound like this. If W[18] > 0 then U[18] >= 0 and U[17 .... U1] = 0. else if W[18] = 0 and W[17] > 0 then U[17] >=0 and U[16.....1] = 0 else if W[16] > 0 then U[16] >=0 and U[15....1] = 0. And so on. Where as W and U are decision variables and I don't know how to do it with binary variables.

```
if (W[18] > 0):
    manpower.addConstr(U[18]>=0)
    for t in range (17, 1,-1):
        manpower.addConstr(U[t] = 0)
elif (W[17] > 0):
    manpower.addConstr(U[17 >= 0])
    for t in range (16, 1, -1):
        manpower.addConstr(U[t] = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to model this using linear inequalities. You cannot use the value of a variable in your formulation to determine whether to add a constraint or not. There is a related concept called indicator constraints and you can read more about this here: [How do I model conditional statements in Gurobi?](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/4414392016529-How-do-I-model-conditional-statements-in-Gurobi-)

Unfortunately, I do not fully understand the logic of your model to provide a concrete solution.